# State of react app is not current with what I have in my database?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am working on a small grocery list application. Whenever I submit a form, I perform an axios request to add the item to the database and update my "items" state to contain the new grocery item.

The issue is, unless I refresh the page, my state still shows an empty "items" array. The "items" array's initial state is pulled from the database, this works through using componentDidMount and setting the state of "items" in there.

Also, in my state, I have currentUser which is also pulled from the database. If I attempt to log this.state.currentUser.shoppingList after adding my first item, it will show an empty array even though I can see the server side log stating the array is not empty.

Here is my code:

```
**App Component**
import React from 'react';
import ListForm from './ListForm';
import * as helpers from '../helpers';

class App extends React.Component{
  state = {
    currentUser: {},
    items: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Hello!');
    helpers.fetchUser()
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          currentUser: data,
          items: data.shoppingList
        }, () => {
          console.log(this.state)
        });
      });
  }

  // Handle adding new items
  onSubmit = (id, item) => {
    this.setState({items: this.state.items.concat([item])});
    helpers.addItem(id, item);
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  // Handle deletion of items
  onDelete = (id, deleteItem) => {
    var shoppingList = this.state.currentUser.shoppingList;
    var index = shoppingList.findIndex(x => x.name === deleteItem);

    console.log(shoppingList);
    helpers.removeItem(id, deleteItem);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container row offset-4">
        <div className="jumbotron col-sm-6">
          <ListForm
            currentUser={this.state.currentUser}
            items={this.state.items}
            onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
            onDelete={this.onDelete}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

**Helpers.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchUser = async () => {
  const resp = await axios.get('/api/current_user');

  return resp.data;
}

export const addItem =  (id, newItem) => {
  const resp = axios.post("/api/" + id + "/addItem", newItem);

  return resp.data;
}

export const removeItem = (id, deleteItem) => {
  const resp = axios.delete("/api/" + id + "/removeItem", {data: {item: deleteItem}});

  return resp.data;
}
```

**ListForm Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import ListItem from './ListItem';

class ListForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: ''
  }

  // Render content based on whether or not currentUser has been returned from
  // our API request.
  renderContent = () => {
    const shoppingList = this.props.currentUser.shoppingList;
    if(shoppingList === null || shoppingList === undefined) {
      return (<h5>Loading List</h5>);
    } else {
        return (
          <div>
            {this.props.items.map((item, index) =>
              <ListItem
                {...item}
                key={index}
                id={index}
                currentUser={this.props.currentUser}
                onDelete={this.props.onDelete}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        );
    }
  }

  // Handle the submission of a new item to database and state.
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.props.onSubmit(this.props.currentUser._id, {name: this.state.value});
    this.setState(prevState => ({value: ''}));
  }

  // Handle any changes within the input.
  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-xs-9">
          <h3>Grocery List</h3>
        <form className="form-control" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input style={{display: "inline", width: "60%", height: "2em"}} className="form-control" type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          <button className="btn btn-success btn-sm float-right">Add item</button>
        </form>
        <div style={{marginTop: "10%"}}>
          {this.renderContent()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ListForm;
```

**ListItem Component**

```
import React from 'react';

const ListItem = props => {

  // Handle delete item requests
  const handleClick = event => {
    var delItem = document.getElementById("btn" + props.id).textContent;

    props.onDelete(props.currentUser._id, delItem);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <li
        style={{display: "inline"}} id={"btn" + props.id} key={props.id}>{props.name}
      </li>
      <button
        style={{display: "inline"}} onClick={e => handleClick(e)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right">
          Remove
      </button>
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
}

export default ListItem;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `render()`, which is called every time the component's state is changed, `componentDidMount()`is called only once, after the component has been "mounted", that is, after its DOM nodes have been inserted in the DOM. For more details regarding the "mounted" term, you might want to check out the [Component Lifecyle Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

In your code, adding an item will modify your client's `state.items` (not `state.currentUser.shoppingList` by the way), and your `fetchUser` function is called only once as being part of the `componentDidMount` client method (reference :
 https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

In other words, when you add an item to the database using `addItem`, your component won't synchronize with your database update because your component's state is not updated to reflect the change that happened in the backend.

If you'd like to sync your user with what you have in the database, then you may call `fetchUser` after having added the item to the database like so :

```
  // Handle adding new items
  onSubmit = (id, item) => {
    this.setState({items: this.state.items.concat([item])});
    helpers.addItem(id, item);
    console.log(this.state);

    helpers.fetchUser()
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          currentUser: data,
          items: data.shoppingList
        }, () => {
          console.log(this.state)
        });
      });
  }
```

I did not test the code though, sorry. Maybe a cleaner way would be to "promisify" your `addItem` function just like you did for `fetchUser`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this should work. Maybe I misunderstood how componentDidMount works. I thought it reset every time the components state changed.

Comment: Sure, I just updated my answer to give more details on this `componentDidMount` function, as well as a reference to the Component Lifecycle that I'm sure you'll find interesting.

Comment: This worked, I essentially changed my code to the same thing I was just not updating items correctly. I had this.setState({items: [...this.state.items, item]}) instead of this.setState({items: data.shoppingList})

Comment: Ah I failed to explain the same :) @PhilippeSultan

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
onSubmit = (id, item) => {
    this.setState({items: this.state.items.concat([item])});
    helpers.addItem(id, item);
    console.log(this.state);
  }
```

Try this:

```
onSubmit = (id, item) => {
    this.setState({items: [...this.state.items,item]});
    helpers.addItem(id, item);
    console.log(this.state);
  }
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work. Until I refresh the page I still get that my this.state.currentUser.shoppingList is empty and items is one item behind on each log.

Comment: Did you check the console? is there any error when you load the page till you add the item?

Comment: There is an initial error when the App first loads as I don't automatically visit "/auth/google" for signing in with google so there is no currentUser. Once I log in and redirect to the App page, I still have to refresh for the page to update after adding a few items. After that first update, the App works fine.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on fiddle or sandbox ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on how to get all my files into jsfiddle. Since I am running a client side server and back end server.

Comment: Try pulling this out: helpers.fetchUser()
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          currentUser: data,
          items: data.shoppingList
        }, () => {
          console.log(this.state)
        });
      }); into a function which you can call after your additem resolves the promise

Comment: No in your code separate the call to get the data in another function and call it when the promise is resolved from addItem

Comment: Tried changing my submit to onSubmit = (id, item) => {
    helpers.addItem(id, item)
      .then(
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          items: [...this.state.items, item]
        }), () => {
          console.log(this.state);
        })
    );
  } This fixes the "items" array not being updated but the data from fetchUser is still not accurate until I refresh.

Comment: after you have added you need to recall the updated data ie. the fetchUser